# Javascript - Need to use clearInterval outside setInterval function

Tags: javascript

Basically, what I have is a setInterval inside a function. What I want to do is, control it's behavior from outside.

Here's what I have -

```
function wheee() {
var i = 1;

slideee = setInterval(function() {
sliderContent.style.marginLeft = margin(i);
    if(i < imagesNoOneLess) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
}, 5000); }
```

Now, I want to clear the interval from outside the `wheee()` function. How can I do that?

I also want to run the interval again, from outside. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are not dangerous, but a pretty way of coding it if you only have one slider is to use an object literal to simulate a singleton object.

```
var Slider= {
    slider: null,
    Start: function(i) {
        this.slider = setInterval(function() {
            // Slider code
            console.log('running: ' + i);
            i++;
        }, 1000);
    },
    Stop: function() {
        window.clearTimeout(this.slider);
    }
};

Slider.Start(1); // Start the slider
Slider.Stop(); // Stop the slider
```

Comment: Don't you mean `window.clearTimeout(this.slider)`?

Edit: But anyway, this seemed like the cleanest solution to me, hence chose you correct.

Comment: Good call, i forgot "this". Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Well the way you've got the code now, it'll probably just work, because you didn't declare "slideee" with `var`.

As long as you somehow export the return value from `setInterval()` you're OK.  You can either make that variable explicitly global (better than having it be implicit), or else have your "wheee" function return the value to its caller.

Comment: I understand what you mean.. But how can I 'export the return value from setInterval'..? I totally lost you there.

Comment: @Namanyayg by "export" I just mean that you need to make sure the value is available outside the function. If you put `var slideee;` outside your function, then the variable will be available globally and you can just call `clearInterval( slideee );`

Comment: As from what I've learnt, global variables are bad. Do you know any way I can avoid the use of global variables?

Comment: @Namanyayg well you could have "wheee" return the value, so that when you call `wheee()` you'd save the timer id: `var timer = wheee();` and then you can call `clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: Do you mean to see, if I add `return slideee` it will work? If I do `var timer = wheee();` I don't think that will work, as `wheee()` contains more things apart from the setInterval.

Also, do you know of any way I can call the setInterval again, once it has been cleared?

Comment: Yes you have to add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Set the scope of `slideee` to be out of `wheee`.

Use objects in order to keep the global scope clean.

Comment: And how do I do that? Sorry, I'm a newb.

Comment: @Namanyayg, the way you have it now, `slideee` is global (because of no `var` declaration). Declare it within the scope you need it keeping it out of the global scope (i.e. write `var slideee;` out of the function).